# Suggesting a question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

A user has made an answer. I have commented it. The back and forth increased. I wasn't able to explain five lines at a time the inner point of a concept. The argument is totally ok in SO. Is it ok if I suggest him to ask a question on SO if he is really interested? There is a POV that it's a little "gaming" the system (or at least there are similar questions on meta on similar arguments) But in the end, if he is interested he will get one or more interesting responses. He will be a better programmer, I'll learn the POV of other persons....

Note that it's probably already covered here: [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to) But that is oneself-to-oneself. Here it's a little different. And then there is this [When is it appropriate to suggest a user start a new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92665/when-is-it-appropriate-to-suggest-a-user-start-a-new-question) but it's about suggestig the OP to make a new question. Yes, I DO know it's like splitting the hair into 4, but I would feel bad if I didn't ask this question :-)

Answer (score 5):

If it is a different question, then it should be posted as a new question.  The OP should probably reference the link to the original question to help provide context.