# What should be done against self-adaptative questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)
>   [How can we help users who repeatedly ask similar questions or update constantly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89292/how-can-we-help-users-who-repeatedly-ask-similar-questions-or-update-constantly)

I've seen today at least three cases of this painful trend : some users (mainly new users) adapt their question by fixing the code while other users fix their errors.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687349/conditional-statement-with-array-using-javascript

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691552/not-work-function#12691552

[Javascript onclick event doesn´t fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689017/javascript-onclick-event-doesnt-fire)

Answerers are forced into a kind of interactive debug session and are forced to always adapt or remove their question while the target keeps moving.

What should be done when this case occurs ?

Comment: See [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) and [How can we help users who repeatedly ask similar questions or update constantly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89292/how-can-we-help-users-who-repeatedly-ask-similar-questions-or-update-constantly)

Comment: @PopularDemand This seems a duplicate. Should I delete the present question, vote to close, else ?

Comment: Note: I rolled back the third question to its 2nd revision and left a comment for the OP. Those interested in what it looked like, please look at the question's revision history.

Comment: Vote to close their question as too localized, downvote, delete, etc. You have the tools to stop this.

Comment: @dystroy I voted to close. Hardest part was deciding which existing post was the better dupe.

Comment: First time I vote to close my own question :)